# Set TTL for API Gateway in Swagger

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, ttl

I'm using cloudformation, and have enabled caching like this:

```
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
  Properties:  
     CacheClusterEnabled: true
     CacheClusterSize: 0.5
```

My methods are taken from swagger. Here's my swagger file for GET

```
/v1/myPath/{id}:
get:
  tags:
    - Books
  operationId: getBook
  parameters:
    - name: id
      in: path
      description: The ID of the book to retrieve
      type: integer
      format: int32
      required: true
    - name: custom-header
      in: header
      type: string
  responses:
    '200':
  x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
    type: aws_proxy
    httpMethod: POST
    uri: arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-1:lambda:path...
    passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
    requestParameters:
      integration.request.header.custom-header: method.request.header.custom-header
    cacheKeyParameters:
      - method.request.header.custom-header
```

How can I set the caching TTL for my GET request in my swagger.yaml? I can't seem to find documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to documentation,

> CacheTtlInSeconds: Integer

```
CacheTtlInSeconds
The time-to-live (TTL) period, in seconds, that specifies how long API Gateway caches responses.

Required: No

Type: Integer
```

**Reference:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-deployment-stagedescription.html

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-methodresponse.html#cfn-apigateway-method-methodresponse-responseparameters

**Cache-Control Documentation:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Way to add headers to cloudformation,

```
ResponseParameters
Response parameters that API Gateway sends to the client that called a method. Specify response parameters as key-value pairs (string-to-Boolean maps), with a destination as the key and a Boolean as the value. Specify the destination using the following pattern: method.response.header.name, where the name is a valid, unique header name. The Boolean specifies whether a parameter is required.

Required: No

Type: Mapping of key-value pairs
```

Comment: That reference modifies the entire stage. I just want to add caching TTL to GET in my swagger.yaml

Comment: That has to be from your GET Integration with Cache-Control header setting with Max Age.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean. Can you leave an example on your answer?

Comment: Added Cache-Control Documentation as I have seen you already integrated http headers to your CF.

Comment: I'm passing a custom-header with a unique value to bypass the cache. Not using max-age. If I manually set the TTL in the aws console, it works fine. I'm just trying to figure out how to set the TTL in either my CF or swagger files.

Comment: In CFN, you can override the stage settings on a per-method basis in the MethodSettings object. This should allow you to set caching only on the GET method you mentioned. The cache cluster type/enabled must be at the Stage level, but 'cachingEnabled' can be set on method. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-deployment-stagedescription-methodsetting.html